# getElementById not returning current text from text area in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

My function document.getelementbyid is not returning the current value of the textarea from HTML page

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4 class="modal-title">PersonName</h4>
    <div  id = 'person_name' class="modal-body">
        <p><%=person['person_name']%></p>
    </div>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Person Description</h4>
    <textarea id="person_descr" style="overflow: scroll; height: 
         100px;"></textarea>
    <button name="button" type="button" class="save" 
           class="btn btn-info" 
            onClick="updateDescription('<%=person['person_name']%>')"> 
            save description </button>       
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateDescription(person_name) {
  var person_name = person_name
  var person_descr = document.getElementById("person_descr").value;
  alert(person_name)
  alert(person_descr)
}
```

In text-area I can edit the existing value and Save that modified value into DB.

When clicked on 'save description' button it is returning 1st element which is passing to text-area but need to get current value of text-area

Comment: You've more than one textarea element, right? And they all have the same `id` ..?

Comment: i fiddled it. no problem here. what is your output ? https://jsfiddle.net/qdmc4s3v/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the shortest code necessary **to reproduce it**_ in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `'` inside your `onClick` function call.

```
onClick="updateDescription('<%=person[\'person_name\']%>')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotations inside your `onclick` aren't being escaped:

```
<button name="button" type="button" class="save" class="btn btn-info" onClick="updateDescription('<%=person[\'person_name\']%>')">save description</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When document load your `textarea` still is empty it show empty at `alert`. You need set value by `person_descr.value = person_name;`

```js
function updateDescription(person_name){

     var person_name= person_name
     
      var person_descr= document.getElementById("person_descr");
       alert(person_name)
       alert(person_descr.value);
       person_descr.value = person_name;
alert(person_descr.value)
       }
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="modal-title">PersonName</h4>
       <div  id = 'person_name' class="modal-body">
       <p>aaa</p>
       </div>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Person Description</h4>
        <textarea id="person_descr" style="overflow: scroll; height: 
         100px;"></textarea>
          <button name="button" type="button" class="save" 
           class="btn btn-info" 
            onClick="updateDescription('aaa')"> 
            save description </button>       
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get a html text area value, you can use the `value` property:

```
document.getElementById("id").value
```

also you have to escape your html quotes:

```
<button name="button" type="button" class="save" 
       class="btn btn-info" 
        onClick="updateDescription('<%=person[\'person_name\']%>')"> 
        save description </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the limitations and awkward syntax of [onevent attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) -- use [onevent properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) or [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) instead. The following demo uses an onevent property.

BTW the button is invalid it has two class attributes:

`<button name="button" type="button"` **class="save" 
           class="btn btn-info"** 
            `onClick="updateDescription('<%=person['person_name']%>')"> 
            save description </button>`

### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = updateDesc;

function updateDesc(e) {
  var personName = document.getElementById("personName");
  var personDesc = document.getElementById("personDesc");
  console.log(personName.textContent);
  console.log(personDesc.value);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Person Name</h4>
  <div id='personName' class="modal-body">
    <p>
      John Doe
    </p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Person Description</h4>
  <textarea id="personDesc" style="overflow: scroll; height: 100px;"></textarea><br>
  <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-info save">Save Description</button>
</div>
```